# upload shapefile in r shiny Error in wk_handle.wk_wkb: Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 0 is degenerate

Tags: r, shiny, geospatial, spatial

I got problem with my r shiny to upload my shapefile. there have message "Warning: Error in wk_handle.wk_wkb: Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 0 is degenerate (duplicate vertex)" below my code

```
data <- read.csv(input$filedata$datapath, header=T, sep=";", fileEncoding = "latin1")
      
      
      data$Jumlah.curah.Hujan <- as.double(gsub(",", ".", data$Jumlah.curah.Hujan))
      data$Suhu <- as.double(gsub(",", ".", data$Suhu))
      data$Kelembaban.Udara <- as.double(gsub(",", ".", data$Kelembaban.Udara))
      data$Kepadatan.penduduk <- as.double(gsub(",", ".", data$Kepadatan.penduduk))
      data$Akses.Sanitasi <- as.double(gsub(",", ".", data$Akses.Sanitasi))
      data$tinggiwilayah <- as.double(gsub(",", ".", data$tinggiwilayah))
      data$Jum.Puskesmas <- as.double(gsub(",", ".", data$Jum.Puskesmas))
      
      
      data$DBD<-ceiling(data$DBD) 
      
      data <- as.data.frame(data)
      #newdata = merge(data, by = "Kabupaten_")
      #newdata
      
      #pl <- st_cast(data$geometry[[4]], "POLYGON")
      #pl
      
      #spd <- sf::as_Spatial(st_geometry(data))
     # class(spd)
      
      #df <- pl
      #df$geometry <- NULL
      #sf_use_s2(FALSE)
      data$E<-expected(data$penduduksum, data$DBD, 16)
      data$E <- as.double(gsub(",", ".", data$E))
      data$SMR<-data$DBD/data$E
      
      a <- readOGR(rute_permission, "shapetemp")
      temp<-poly2nb(a)
      
      W<-nb2mat(temp, style = "B", zero.policy = TRUE)
      
      sum_matrix<-colSums(W)
      for(i in 1:length(sum_matrix)){
        if(sum_matrix[i]==0){
          W[i,i]=1
        }
      }
      
      Wlist<-nb2listw(temp,style = "B", zero.policy = TRUE)
```